# Does Laravel's rollback transaction support polymorphic relations?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, transactions, polymorphism

I've got these polymorphic relations:

```
staff: 
id - integer
name - string

orders:
id - integer
price - integer

photos:
id - integer
path - string
imageable_id - integer
imageable_type - string
```

And in a controller:

```
public function example() {

    \DB::beginTransaction();

    try {

            $staff = Staff::findOrFail(1);

            $row = $staff->photos()->create([ 'path' => 1 ]);

            $row->path = 2;
            $row->save();

            abort(445);

   } catch( \Exception $e ) {

      \DB::rollback()
   }

}
```

As expected, the current row must be deleted from photos table, but it's still there with path = 2

Do I think in a right away? or It's a misundertanding?

Comment: Where is the polymorphic relation post your models also you can use `DB::transaction` & pass as a closure function which automatically begin transaction & rollback you won't have to handle it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not rolling back the transaction, there is one possibility that your table has `MyISAM` as the engine, since MyISAM tables do not support rollbacks.

So double-check that the table's engine is correctly set to `InnoDB`.